# TFS merging files that haven't changed, aren't even in the changeset

Tags: visual-studio-2010, merge

I have two feature branches off of Main, FB1 and FB2. I have a single changeset in FB1. I need the changeset in FB2, but policy forbids me from merging it into Main at this time. So I run the baseless merge commandline:

```
Tf merge /baseless "$/FB1" "$/FB2" /recursive
```

Unexpectedly, TFS reports that **every** single file in the entire tree needs to be merged. After searching, I can find no explanation for why this is happening. Then I explicitly stated that I just wanted the one changeset:

```
Tf merge /baseless "$/FB1" "$/FB2" /recursive /version:C1436
```

I got the same result. It still says every single file needs to be merged. But the changeset only has two altered files in it. I expect that only the two files that changed  would be merged. Why is TFS not behaving as I expect?

Also, is there some way to find out why TFS wants to merge two files? When I diff any of the files they are the same, so how do I determine what TFS **does** see as different?

**UPDATE**

What actually happened was that we renamed the root folder in one of the branches (I don't remember the exact setup) and that made TFS see everything as different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for the operation that you want is as follows. This says "Merge only changeset 1436 from FB1 to FB2."

```
tf merge /baseless /recursive $/FB1;C1436~C1436 $/FB2
```

Thanks,
P. Kelley

Comment: This produces the same result. Every single file in the tree is marked as merged, even though changeset 1436 only has two files that changed. Something must have gone wrong in our branching/merging process.